# is it possible to choose points on the graph of $y = x^2$ to form vertices of an equilateral triangle?

Tags: geometry

is it possible to choose points on the graph of $y = x^2$ to form vertices of an equilateral triangle $\Delta ABC$?where three ponit not $(0,0)$ .and find $(S_{\Delta ABC})_{min}$

Comment: You should play with some numbers: If we fix one vertex to be $(0,0)$, and the other vertices are $(-a,a^2)$ and $(a,a^2)$. Then, the distance from $(0,0)$ to the other vertices is $\sqrt{a^2+a^4}$, and the distance between the other two vertices is $2a$. So, does $2a = \sqrt{a^2+a^4}$ have a solution? Yes, $a=\sqrt{3}$ works. So, it's possible.

Comment: @Batman Why don't you make that an answer?

Comment: @N.S.JOHN it doesn't answer the second question (though presumably it is indeed the minimizing such triangle)

Comment: if one vertex to be not $(0.0)$? How to prove there exist such equilateral triangle?

Comment: You can take the algebraic geometry approach, and set up equations. It appears that there is an equilateral triangle for each point on the parabola. The tough part is to find where the minimum occurs.

Comment: Mathematica says that minimum edge length $= 12, a = -\sqrt3, b = 0, c = \sqrt3$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Summary**

- Are there other points which can form equilateral triangle?

  The answer is yes. In fact, there are infinitely many of them.
  The centroids of the triangles lie on another parabola $y = 9x^2 + 2$.
- The minimal area is $3\sqrt{3}$. achieved by the equilateral triangle with vertices $(0,0)$, $(\pm\sqrt{3},3)$.

---

Identify the euclidean plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with complex plane $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $z = x + iy$ and $\bar{z} = x - iy$ be its complex conjugate, the equation of the parabola becomes

$$y = x^2 \iff \frac{z - \bar{z}}{2i} = \left(\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}\right)^2 \iff
(z + \bar{z})^2 + 2i(z-\bar{z}) = 0$$

Let $\omega = e^{2\pi i/3}$. Given any equilateral triangle $T$, we can always find two complex numbers $\rho = u+iv$ and $a$ such that the vertices of $T$ are $\rho + a\omega^k$ for $k = 0, \pm 1$.

If they all lie on the parabola above, then for $k = 0, \pm 1$, we have
$$
\begin{align}
 &\; (\rho + \bar{\rho} + a\omega^k + \bar{a}\omega^{-k})^2
+  2i(\rho - \bar{\rho} + a\omega^k - \bar{a}\omega^{-k})\\
= &\; (\rho+\bar{\rho})^2
 +  2(\rho+\bar{\rho})(a\omega^k + \bar{a}\omega^{-k})
 + (a^2\omega^{-k} + 2|a|^2 + \bar{a}^2\omega^k)
 + 2i(\rho - \bar{\rho} + a\omega^k - \bar{a}\omega^{-k})\\
= &\; 0
\end{align}
$$
Comparing coefficients of different powers of $\omega$, we get

$$
\begin{cases}
(\rho + \bar{\rho})^2 + 2i(\rho - \bar{\rho}) + 2|a|^2 &= 0\\
2(\rho + \bar{\rho} + i)a + \bar{a}^2 &= 0\\
2(\rho + \bar{\rho} - i)\bar{a} + a^2 &= 0
\end{cases}
$$
Multiply the $2^{nd}$ equation by $4a^2$ and simplify it using $1^{st}$ equation, 
we get
$$8(\rho + \bar{\rho} +i )a^3 + \left[(\rho + \bar{\rho})^2 + 2i(\rho - \bar{\rho})\right]^2 = 0\tag{*1}$$
Since $\rho + \bar{\rho} + i = 2u + i\ne 0$, we can use this to determine $a$ up to a factor $\omega^k$.

For this $a$ to be compatible with the $1^{st}$ equation, the condition is

$$\begin{align}
& (\rho + \bar{\rho})^2 + 2i(\rho - \bar{\rho}) = -2|a|^2 = -8|\rho + \bar{\rho} + i|^2
= -8 ((\rho+\bar{\rho})^2 + 1)\\
\iff & 9(\rho + \bar{\rho})^2 + 2i(\rho - \bar{\rho}) + 8 = 36u^2 - 4v + 8 = 0\\
\iff & v = 9u^2 + 2
\end{align}
$$
Base on this, we see start from any point $(u,v)$ from the  parabola $y = 9x^2 + 2$, if one define $\rho = u + iv$ and use $(*1)$ to compute $a$, the 3 points
$\rho + a\omega^k$ will lie on the original parabola
$y = x^2$ and form an equilateral triangle.

Back to question of minimization of area. It is clear it is equivalent to
minimization of $|a|$. Since

$$|a|^2 = -\frac12 \left[ (\rho + \bar{\rho})^2 + 2i(\rho - \bar{\rho}) \right]
= 2(v-u^2) = 2(2+8u^2)$$

the minimal value $|a|$ is achieved at $(u,v) = (0,2)$ with value $2$.
The corresponding triangle has vertices at $(0,0)$, $(\pm\sqrt{3},3)$ 
with side length $2\sqrt{3}$ and area $3\sqrt{3}$.