# Find latus rectum of locus of centroid of equilateral triangle inscribed in parabola x^2 = 36y?

Tags: conic-sections

This is not a homework help question, I found a problem when I was doing self-study , but I am getting stuck. Please tell me if my method is right, or if there are other steps I need to take.

Since the parabola is in the form $x^2 = 4ay$ where $a=9$, I deduced that the vertices of the triangle will be $A(9t_1^2,18t_1)$, $B(9t_2^2,18t_2)$ and $C(9t_3^3,18t_3)$. The $x$ and $y$ coordinates of centroid $h$ and $k$ will thus be given by the sum of coordinates of the vertices
$h = 6(t_1+t_2+t_3)$ and $y = 3(t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2)$.

However I do not know how to find out if this is a conic section.
I also wondered if I should use the fact that the centroid divides the median in the ratio 2:1, and thus got $h = 3t_1^2+6(t_2+t_3)$ and $k = 6t_1 + 3(t_2^2+t_3^2)$

However none of these incorporate the fact that the triangle is an equilateral triangle. I do not know how to proceed or what method to take. Would someone please help me? The answer is that the length of the latus rectum is 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given parabola $\mathcal{P} : 4ay = x^2$ with parametrization $\mathbb{R} \ni t \mapsto \rho(t) = (2at,at^2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Let $v_1, v_2, v_3$ be any $3$ points on $\mathcal{P}$ whose parameters $t_1, t_2, t_3$ satisfy $t_1 < t_2 < t_3$.
Consider the triangle formed using these vertices. Let

- $\theta_1$ be the angle between the side $v_1v_2$ with $x$-axis.
- $\theta_2$ be the angle between the side $v_2v_3$ with $x$-axis

It is easy to see
$$
\tan\theta_1 = \frac{at_2^2 - at_1^2}{2at_2 - 2at_1} = \frac{t_2+t_1}{2}\quad\text{ and }\quad
\tan\theta_2 = \frac{at_3^2 - at_2^2}{2at_3 - 2at_2} = \frac{t_3+t_2}{2}
$$
In order for $v_1, v_2, v_3$ to form an equilateral triangle, the exterior
angle at $v_2$ has to be $120^\circ$.
This means

$$\frac{\tan\theta_2 - \tan\theta_1}{1 + \tan\theta_2\tan\theta_1}
= \tan(\theta_2-\theta_1) = \tan 120^\circ = -\sqrt{3}$$

Plugging expression of $\tan\theta_1$, $\tan\theta_2$ into above and simplify.
Do the same thing to other two vertices, we obtain:

$$
\begin{align}
4 + (t_3+t_2)(t_2+t_1) + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(t_3 - t_1) = 0\\
4 + (t_1+t_3)(t_3+t_2) + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(t_1 - t_2) = 0\\
4 + (t_2+t_1)(t_1+t_3) + \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}(t_2 - t_3) = 0
\end{align}
$$
Summing these equations, we obtain
$$\begin{align}
 &(t_1+t_2)(t_2+t_3) + (t_2+t_3)(t_3+t_1)+(t_3+t_1)(t_1+t_2) + 12 = 0\\
\iff & t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2 + 3(t_1t_2+t_2t_3+t_3t_1) + 12 = 0\\
\iff & t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2 = 3(t_1+t_2+t_3)^2 + 24
\end{align}
$$
The centroid of the triangle is located at
$(x_c,y_c) = \left(\frac{2a}{3}(t_1+t_2+t_3),\frac{a}{3}(t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2)\right)$. Above equality implies $(x_c,y_c)$ is lying on the curve

$$\frac{3y_c}{a} = 3\left(\frac{3x_c}{2a}\right)^2 + 24
\quad\iff\quad 4ay_c = 9 x_c^2 + 32a^2
$$
For $a = 9$, this becomes $4 y_c = x_c^2 + 288$, a parabola with latus rectum $4$.

There are other ways to show the locus is a parabola.
For an alternate approach using complex numbers, see
[my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1763693/59379) to a related
question about the parabola $y = x^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was a very great help to me!

Comment: I'm really sorry to trouble you after so long, actually I found one more solution and it is not properly detailed. I just want to know how it works. Would you please help me? This is what is written in my book:

Comment: Circumcircle equation for (at^2,2at) is a^2 t^4 + 4a^2 t^2 + 2gat^2 + 4fat + c = 0. Since centroid and circumcircle coincide -g = 2a(t1+t2+t3)/2, -f = a/3(t1^2 + t2^2 + t3^2) so required locus is x^2 = 4(y-72). I don't understand this solution, but learning to do this problem using circumcircle as well would be helpful for me. Would you please explain it to me? What step should I take after -g = 2a(t1+t2+t3)/2, -f = a/3(t1^2 + t2^2 + t3^2)?

Comment: @Hema Let $t_1, t_2, t_3, t_4$ be the roots of the circumcircle equation.  By Vieta's formula, $t_1 + t_2 + t_3 + t_4 = 0$ and
$$\begin{align}
\frac{4a^2 - 2y_ca}{a^2} &= (t_1+t_2+t_3)t_4 + t_1t_2 + t_2t_3 + t_3t_1\\
&= -\frac12\left((t_1+t_2+t_3)^2 + (t_1^2+t_2^2+t_3^2)\right)
 = -\frac12\left(\left(\frac{3x_c}{2a}\right)^2 + \frac{3y_c}{a}\right)\end{align}$$
which can be simplified to $4ay_c = 9x_c^2+32a^2$.

Comment: Thank you so much! It was a very great help to me.